# How to assign a controller for ListWheelScrollView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I am using a `ListWheelScrollView` that is using `physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),`. I have used various other `ScrollControllers` in my app. I want to supply a parameter to my `ListWheelScrollView` so that it uses the **same** `ScrollController` as the rest of my widgets. However it does not allow me to supply the `controller:mainController` parameter along with `FixedExtentScrollPhysics()`. How can I solve this?

Here this is the declaration of mainController, the on that I'm trying to call in `ListWheelScrollView` :

```
final mainController = ScrollController();
```

The code for my list is :

```
ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
              itemExtent: 90,
              perspective: 0.0025,
              magnification: 1.2,
              physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
              diameterRatio: 4,
              // controller: mainController,
              offAxisFraction: 0.42,
              useMagnifier: true,
              childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                  builder: (
                    context,
                    index,
                  ) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          isThreeLine: false,
                          trailing: indexTrailing(index, duration, true),
                          title: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 60,
                                    width: 60,
                                    child: Image.network(
                                        'https://www.ikea.com/in/en/images/products/smycka-artificial-flower-rose-red__0903311_PE596728_S5.JPG'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'Hello',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                        wordSpacing: 0,
                                        letterSpacing: 0,
                                        textStyle: kTasksStyle.copyWith(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: kDarkBlue,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          0.62,
                                      child: RichText(
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        text: TextSpan(
                                          text: "This is a rose",
                                          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                            textStyle: kTasksStyle.copyWith(
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                color: kGrey,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 18.0, right: 18, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                          child: Divider(
                            height: 1,
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                            thickness: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: 9),
            ),
```

This is the error that I get when I supply the `controller` parameter along with `FixedExtentScrollPhysics()`:

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart': Failed assertion: line 504 pos 12: 'haveDimensions == (_lastMetrics != null)': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListWheelScrollView
```

and

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
FixedExtentScrollPhysics can only be used with Scrollables that uses the FixedExtentScrollController
'package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart':
Failed assertion: line 485 pos 7: 'position is _FixedExtentScrollPosition'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use;

```
     FixedExtentScrollController();
```

instead of

```
     ScrollController();
```